# ES 6.x - histogram script with timezone

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to make query to get date histgoram with specific timezone.

```
"aggregations": {
        "time": {
          "histogram": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['write_at'].date.setZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(tz)); doc['write_at'].date.hourOfDay",
              "lang": "groovy",
              "params": {
                "tz": "+09:00"
              }
            },
            "interval": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            },
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": 0,
              "max": 23
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

It worked with ES 5.x, but doesn't work with ES 6.2.
This is error from query.

> { "type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "script_lang not
>   supported [groovy]" }

When I change script language as "painless", another error comes up.

```
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "compile error",
"script_stack": [
"... 'start_at'].date.setZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZon ..."
,
" ^---- HERE"
],
"script": "doc['start_at'].date.setZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID(tz)); doc['start_at'].date.hourOfDay",
"lang": "painless"
}
```

How should I do with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like that should work. I have no way to test it now.

```
"script": {   
  "inline": "Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc.write_at.date.millis).atZone(ZoneId.of(params.tz)).hour",   
  "lang": "painless",
  "params": {
    "tz": "Europe/Zurich"
  }
}
```